# gnome key binding one third window size

Tags: resize, key-bindings, gnome

I'd like to create key-bindings that set the current window size to one third the screen size horizontally and maximal vertically and locate it on the left, middle, or right one third of the screen.  How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**xbindkeys and xdotool**

With xbindkeys you can use shortctus independently from the window manager.
xdotool allows to move and resize windows.

Install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys 
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

**Default Configuration**

The default setting are showing what the shortcut bindings might look like. Create it and take a look at the file contents.

```
xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

Use a editor to edit ~/.xbindkeysrc and enter:

```
"/bin/bash ~/placewindow.sh left"
    control + l

"/bin/bash ~/placewindow.sh middle"
    control + m

"/bin/bash ~/placewindow.sh right"
    control + r
```

**Create shell script**

Create a shell script with a text editor, for our use case I have named it ~/placewindow.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

width=`xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)).*$/\2/'`
height=`xdpyinfo | grep dimensions | sed -r 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)).*$/\3/'`

case "$1" in
    left)       
       xdotool windowsize `xdotool getactivewindow` `expr $width / 3` $height
       xdotool windowmove `xdotool getactivewindow` 0 0
       ;;
    middle)
       xdotool windowsize `xdotool getactivewindow` `expr $width / 3` $height
       xdotool windowmove `xdotool getactivewindow` `expr $width / 3` 0
       ;;
    right)
       xdotool windowsize `xdotool getactivewindow` `expr $width / 3` $height
       xdotool windowmove `xdotool getactivewindow` `expr $width \* 2 / 3` 0
       ;;
esac
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x placewindow.sh
```

**Hints**

After making changes to  ~/.xbindkeysrc you need to

```
killall xbindkeys
xbindkeys
```

to make the changes active immediately.

**Demo**

When pressing now CTRL+l, CTRL+m, or CTRL+r the active window gets sized and located. It looks like this:

[image: window sizing demo]

Comment: Awesome!  I couldn't get it to work with xbindkeys, but combining your code with the keybindings from the gnome keyboard menu item did the trick!  And best thing of all: you taught me how to fish instead of just giving me a fish. ;-)